# TS2306 is not a module error on typescript file

Tags: typescript

So I'm getting this error for my typescript file. I don't understand why it's not working. From what I understand this is what you need to do to export a class. But I keep getting an error that my file is not a module and can't be imported.

Error

> TS2306 is not a module error on typescript file

```js
export default class GridApi{
    Hello(): string {
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

Also here is my tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you importing it? And does it compile?

Comment: import GridApi from './GridApi'; It has randomly compiled once. Otherwise I keep getting failed to compile

Comment: Okay that's not how that works. You need to include all the relevant details in a **minimal, verifiable, reproduceable, complete example** MVCE. We can't help you if you just tell us about the problem. What is the **exact** error your getting when you try to compile your ts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `module` setting is set to `CommonJS`, which is not what you want. [CommonJS modules](https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/) use the `require` syntax, but you use `import/export`. You should instead use `ES6` modules:

```json
"module": "ES6",
```

[Read more about TSC options here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: It's hard to know if this is the actual issue, but it could very well be. Leaving `"module": "CommonJS"` will just ensure that the resulting compiled Javascript uses `require(...)` on the importing side, and `exports.` on the exporting side.

Comment: Yeah, I really wish I could provide more information but the nature of my work I can't disclose just about anything. It's complicated. As far as the code provided is concerned its just about exactly what I'm trying to do with a simple import on the other side. So with this advice I was able to get it to work but I had to add export { GridApi } to the module instead of using. Don't know why that works but I'm really new to ts so whats important is I appreciate the help. Cheers!